# How to sort mongo documents on find results

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection which has 10 million data. I have two main fields `domain` (string type) and `level`(integer type). Both fields are indexed, but when I sort the results after find statement, mongo is taking a lot of time to return the results.

How to sort the results fast from find statement?

```
db.collection.find({"domain":"DOMAIN_NAME"}).sort({"level":1})
```

Comment: What is `Cr`? This collection is sharded or not?

Comment: Using `.explain()` (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) will shed some light on how Mongo is actually performing your query, it's usually good first step when indexes and speed come into play

Comment: Also how many objects are in your returning results? If mongo tries to sort 100K documents it will be slow. @ malarzm point very well on explain. Also take a look at projection to exclude fields you actually don't need. Less data to return => faster query.

Comment: Though I have limited return data to only 2 fields, i'n not getting results faster. I want to sort around 2 lakh recods
@SergeyBerezovskiy: cr means crore

Comment: @VenkataNaresh what is crore? what is lakh?

Comment: You say "both fields are indexed", but unless you've defined one compound index of `{domain: 1, level: 1}`, the sort won't be able to use an index. Can you update your question to show the output of `db.collection.getIndexes()`?

Comment: Please don't use Indian words (like crore) and definitely not abbreviations of Indian words.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, even if both fields are indexed separately, I believe intersection indexes will be used, provided that they are in the same direction.

Comment: @JohnnyHK: what is the difference between indexing fields seperately and compound indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments, it appears you have created two separate indexes: one on `domain` and one on `level`. Those indexes cannot be combined to support your sort when paired with that query.

From [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-intersection/#index-intersection-and-sort):

> Index intersection does not apply when the `sort()` operation requires an index completely separate from the query predicate.

Instead, you'll need to add a new compound index that includes both fields, with the `domain` field first as that's what you're querying on:

```
db.collection.createIndex({domain: 1, level: 1})
```

You can learn more about MongoDB indexes [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/).